# Grouping Mysql PHP Query Results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic PHP page which searches a MySQL Database of retro ZX Spectrum magazine articles.

The address is [www.retroresource.co.uk][1]

The PHP Results Page is fine, in that it produced the results, but I would like to be able to group the results by 'fgames.fgname'

So for example if I searched for Dizzy

Dizzy (as a header)

Table with rows that have fgames.fgname = Dizzy

Spindizzy (as a header)

Table with rows that have fgames.fgname = Spindizzy

Treasure Island Dizzy (as a header)

Table with rows that have fgames.fgname = Treasure Island Dizzy

etc etc

I have googled and looked in a few of my text books, but am unable to see a solution.  Any help much appreciated.

Peter

Amended Code after assistance (No results though)

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);


require( '../connect_db.php' ) ;

$query = $_GET['query']; 


$min_length = 4;
// you can set minimum length of the query if you want

$query = strip_tags($query); 

$query = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc,$query);


$q = "SELECT fgames.fgname, fgames.fgprorg, fgames.fgprbud, fgames.fgratng, fgames.fgprdsk, ftypes.fttname, frefs.fryymm, frefs.frpage, frefs.frissue, fmagzne.fmname, frefcde.ffname
FROM fgames, ftypes,frefs, fmagzne,frefcde
WHERE ftypes.fttype = fgames.fgtype
and   fgames.fglink = frefs.frlink2
and   frefs.frentry = frefcde.ffentry
and   frefs.frmag = fmagzne.fmmag 
and   fgames.fgname LIKE '%".$query."%'
order by fgames.fgname ASC" ;

$r = mysqli_query( $dbc , $q ) ;


$current_group = '';
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r , MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) 

{
    if($row['fgames.fgname']) !== $current_group) 

{

       if($current_group !== '') 
{
           echo '</table>';
}
      $current_group = $row['fgames.fgname'];

      echo '<table><tr><th>FGNAME</th><th>FGPRORG</th><th>FGRBUD</th><th>FGRATNG</th><th>FGRDSK</th>
      <th>FTTTNAME</th><th>FRYYMM</th><th>FRPAGE</th><th>FRISSUE</th><th>FMNAME</th><th>FFNAME</th></tr>';

}
 echo '<tr><td>'.$row['fgname'].'</td><td>'.$row['fgprorg'].'</td><td> '.$row['fgprbud'].' </td><td>'.$row['fgratng'].' </td>            <td>'.$row['fgprdsk'].' </td><td>'.$row['fttname'].'</td><td> '.$row['fryymm'].'</td><td> '.$row['frpage'].'</td><td> '.$row['frissue'].' </td> <td>'.$row['fmname'].' </td><td>'.$row['ffname'].'</td></tr>';

}

echo '</table>';

else
{
  echo '<p>' . mysqli_error( $dbc ) . '</p>'  ;
}








# Close the connection.
mysqli_close( $dbc ) ;
?>
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this? Your code does not seem to show what you have done to try to implement this.

Comment: Hi,  I have Googled, but not managed to find anything similar that I can base it on.  I'm assuming in the SQL I need a Group By? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic approaches.

Either load the query data into a two dimensional array and output with nested loop like this:

```
$array_for_output = array();
while($row = /* your query fetch mechanism here */) {
    $array_for_output[$row['field_you_are_grouping_on']] = $row;
}

foreach($array_for_output as $table_name => $table_data) {
    // output table header here
    foreach($table_data as $table_row) {
        // output individual row
    }
    // output table closure here
}
```

Or the other approach is to query using an `ORDER BY` clause on the field you are trying to group by and detect changes in the current group in single loop

```
$query = "
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY field_you_are_grouping_on, any_secondary_ordering_field_here ASC";

// execute query here

$current_group = '';
while ($row = /* your query fetch mechanism here */) {
    if($row['field_you_are_grouping_on']) !== $current_group) {
       // we have started a new group
       if($current_group !== '') {
           // this is not first table
           // so output closure to previous table here
       }
       $current_group = $row['field_you_are_grouping_on'];
       // output new table header here
    }
    // output row data here
}
// output closure to final table here
```

The second approach is usually preferable from a memory management standpoint (you don't have to store entire result set in memory at any point), but some beginning developers may not find this not as intuitive as the first method.  The first method also may be more appropriate if you want to take the full result set and inject it into some sort of template that is used to render the display.

Comment: Hi,  I have changed the code, but I get no results.  I have added the amended code to my original Post.  Thank you.

Comment: @PeterJones Does your query actually work? I don't see where you are even verifying that it works before trying to work with the result set. Also please learn how to use proper code indentation.  It is a mess to try to read your code.

Comment: @PeterJones You also are not referring the the fields properly in your code.  Unless you alias your fields in the SELECT, you will need to access them like `$row['fgames.fgname']`.

Comment: Sorry Mike about my indendation, I was checking the numbers of brackets so moved around the code.

Comment: @MikeBurgess Sorry Mike, added the full field names and still no results. Peter

Comment: @PeterJones Get a good IDE.  Any decent will show you open/closing bracket highlighting.  Have you done any debugging to see where script execution varies from what you are expecting? You are also very vulnerable to SQL injection, so you might consider using prepared statements (but that is another topic). Consider if someone passed this value for your parameter `%;DROP TABLE fgames;`

Comment: OK, I will get an IDE.  Any suggestions as to what is wrong would be appreciated. Peter

Comment: @PeterJones I don't know without any debugging information.  You should add error handling around all your database interactions for starters. YOu should `var_dump()` i different parts of your script to verify the variables values you get are what you expect. Do this until you narrow down the problem at a point where script execution varies from what you expect.

Comment: Again. A good IDE and good code formatting would show this to you immediately as you are writing code.  They are invaluable as you start getting more into coding.