# Is it possible to avoid query in loop?

Tags: php, mysql, query-performance

I have such code:

```
$q = "SELECT date FROM t1 GROUP BY date";
$pdo->query($q);
$results = $pdo->results();

foreach($results as $result) {
    echo "<h1>$result['date']</h1>";
    echo "<table>";

    $q = "SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE date=:date";
    $pdo->query($q);
    $pdo->bind("date", $result['date']);
    $subresults = $pdo->resultset();

    foreach($subresults as $sub) {
        echo "<tr><td>$sub['smth']</td></tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
```

It reads dates from database and prints separate tables with data. It is possible to achieve this without having query in a loop?

Comment: This is pretty close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222654/grouping-mysql-php-query-results

Comment: and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468584/how-to-display-data-from-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order the results by date, instead of group by. Then, you can use some if conditions to render the `h1` and `table` tags:

```
$q = "SELECT `smth`, `date` FROM `t1` ORDER BY `date`";
$pdo->query($q);
$results = $pdo->results();

$currentDate = '';
foreach($results as $index => $result) {
    if ($currentDate != $result['date']) {
        if ($index != 0) {
            echo "</table>";
        }

        echo "<h1>{$result['date']}</h1>";
        echo "<table>";
    }

    echo "<tr><td>{$result['smth']}</td></tr>";

    $currentDate = $result['date'];
}

echo "</table>";
```

---

***NB:*** Not tested